# Multiple Images with JScrollPane in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Ok, I am trying to add one row of multiple images to a JPanel, it can range from 15 - 30 images so I need to have a horizontal Scroll Pane in the JPanel.

Now comes the hard part, how can I make it so the images can be removed then a new amount of images can be in its place?

Comment: @Cody Please post the code you have used to achieve this: `add one row of multiple images to a JPanel,`, because the answer would depend on it.

Comment: I think you mean have a jpanel in a horizontal scroll pane, or better yet a JScrollPane that provides the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can either:**

a) remove the images individually from the panel using the `remove()` method and then `revalidate()` the panel

**Or**

b) create a new panel with the new images and then add the panel to the scrollpane using the `setViewportView(...)` method.

Comment: Another question, how do I make it to where it cant display 1/2 an image? And thank you very much!

Comment: +1 @Cody: if the widths are homogeneous, `getViewport().setPreferredSize()` to a multiple of the width; http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html